# "Besides" and "Beside that". Do they have the same meaning in this kind of sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I don't mind spending Friday and Saturday nights waiting tables at a snack bar after having spent the whole week working in a factory. I like the customers and they seem to like me and I really have nothing better to do. **Besides** / **Beside that**, the tips have been a big help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native speaker of English, I would use "besides" here.  I would say "beside that" in a sentence like this:  "Riding a roller coaster is so much fun!  Beside that, riding in a car is dull."  In this sentence the idiom means the same thing as "in contrast".

Comment: I've just trawled the entire entry for ***beside*** in the *full* (subscription-only)  Oxford English Dictionary. They don't even list ***beside = in contrast, by comparison, in the context of,...*** as an *obsolete* sense. I say it *never* has / had that meaning, and your roller coaster example uses ***beside*** incorrectly.

Comment: I disagree.  Here's an entry from the Cambridge Dictionary.  "Compared to another person or thing:  Those books seem very dull beside this one."  There is a distinction between "compare" and "contrast", one showing similarity, the other showing differences.  I contend that the Cambridge example shows contrast, not similarity, but it's a quibble.

Comment: Well, since we're both native speakers who both obviously think we know our own language, I don't suppose either of us are going to change our mind. I see that Merriam-Webster has a similar definition, for which the example usage is *potential complications are minor beside the benefits*. So I checked [actual published written usage for that construction.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+minor+beside+the%2Care+minor+compared+to+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I think the results speak for themselves, and I wouldn't advise learners to use it.

Comment: Here's another instructive link on [Textranch](https://textranch.com/154830/besides-that/or/beside-that/).  Examples with "Besides that" are much more numerous, but I contend this is because in these examples the phrase generally mean "additionally", whereas examples with the phrase "beside that" pertain to contrasts, and it's more common to provide additional information than to provide contrasting information.  This is very much a matter of my opinion, I concede.